# Square brackets in XML?

Tags: xml, escaping, special-characters

In an XML document, how do I treat square brackets (] or [) ?

Comment: [CDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a better solution.  But this works:

```
&#x005D;
```

as in:

```
<blah value="&#x005D;"></blah>
```

then again, so does (see Kirtan's answer):

```
<blah value="]"></blah>
```

Answer (score 16):

Square brackets do not need a specific notation in XML but they have a special meaning when used in XPath expressions for XSL transformations.

```
<root>
  <el attrib="[">[</el>
</root>
```

Comment: Funny, your answer is a direct copy from http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?179876-Square-bracket-in-XML&s=b87a278d249ac6da80b2395c7f4daa26&p=883259#post883259

Answer (score 1):

"**>**" does not require to be escaped.

"**]**" does not require to be escaped.

"**]]>**" require to be escaped as part of the CDATA element.